# Codeigniter Selecting from an array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

This will be simple for someone, and I have looked it up but don't understand why my syntax returns blank.

```
$this ->adminship_model->get_admininfo();
```

Returns an Array;

```
'username' => $this->adminship_model->get_admininfo(),
```

put in the session stores an array and when I print_r it, I can see the array of data.

```
[UserName] => SomeUserName
```

Is in the array

```
$variable = $this ->adminship_model->get_admininfo();
```

Sets the array to that variable

```
'username' => $this->$varaible->UserName,
```

returns blank

```
'username' => $this->$variable['UserName'],
```

returns blank

```
'username' => $variable['UserName'],
```

returns blank

What am I doing wrong please. Sorry if it is simple, I'll only need told once. :)

Comment: Show what you're trying to do in context, because unless it's just me that post makes no sense at all.

Comment: Can't follow this question. Please just post your raw code!

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused by your syntax, but it looks like you should have

```
$variable = $this->adminship_model->get_admininfo(); // space removed
$user_name = $variable['UserName'];
echo $user_name;
```

That should echo `SomeUserName`